# "Delete this Add-In" event for uninitializing own ArcMap Add-In

Tags: arcobjects, c#

Is there an event that gets triggered, when removing an Add-In by pressing the "Delete this Add-In" button in the Add-In Manager - using ArcMap 10.x?

[image]

I want to listen to this event to let my Add-In automatically remove any toolbars, close all dockable windows that came with my Add-In, etc.

Comment: Did you test to see if deleting the add-in fires `IExtension.Shutdown` ?  If so, it seems like you could do your cleanup there. If your addin doesn't include an Extension, perhaps consider implementing one solely for the purpose of cleanup.

Comment: Yes, this was my first intention. It seems that the Extension class from the AddIns namespace (`ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.Addins`) does not implement IExtension (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/Extension_Class/001v000000vz000000/). But it has the `OnShutdown()` method, which only gets called, when the extension is unloaded. But the extension won't be unloaded when deleting the add-in - using the Add-In Manager. I also tried the `OnSetState()` method but with no success.